# PHP cron script firing more than once a minute

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a cron job that appears to be running more than once a minute, not sure how that's possible considering linux only handles in minute intervals. Here's how I've researched it.

First, I confirmed that there aren't any additional entries in /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily etc... nothing unusual there.

Then, I went into /etc/crontab to make sure there were no additional entries, nothing there.

Then, I ran this command to see crontabs for all users

`for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done`

... nothing there, however, the root did not show up, but perhaps this is expected

Finally, I hit `crontab -l`

and all I get was one entry as expected:

`* * * * * wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://...cron_custom_alerts.php`

Based on the above, I assume there really is only one cron job configured. However, I added logging to the script that is running, and I see more than one execution per minute. I output both the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR]' just in case the cron is being executed externally. However, the log doesn't show any remote IP, and doesn't give any clues other than what I suspected which that it is running multiple times.

```
2012-05-02 21:57:01 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:57:47 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:57:53 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:58:01 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:58:48 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:58:54 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:59:01 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:59:47 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 21:59:53 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY 
2012-05-02 22:00:01 - /cron_custom_alerts.php EXECUTED BY
```

It appears they were running in batches of three. When I entered crontab and commented out the one entry, it brought it down to two! So apparently, there are two more hidden jobs somewhere calling this script, but it isn't visible via `crontab -e`

If there is more logging I can do via PHP, I'm open to that but I've really hit a wall in being able to investigate what's triggering this script execution.

ANSWER: Access logs indicated that script was being accessed externally and not by any internal cron jobs. Other servers were blocked from executing the cron via htaccess deny.

Comment: Attach `strace` to the `cron` daemon and try to catch it in action.

Comment: Did you `sudo` or run as root the list of crontab for all users?  You cannot view other user's crontab unless you're root. What is the PHP script doing? Could the PHP write the log in a function that is called multiple times?

Comment: It's extremely odd that the script is executed in the webserver environment via http request, yet the $_SERVER variables are blank. In fact...you misspelled them. It's $_S not $S, although I don't think you'll learn much from seeing those values.

Comment: One shot in the dark: is your PHP page outputting a link that refers to itself? Maybe `wget` is following the link.

Comment: The server variables are correct in the script itself and only $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is blank. The PHP page doesn't appear to output anything.

Comment: I did all the above investigation as root

Comment: And to clarify $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = /cron_custom_alerts.php in the log

Comment: Since you're hitting it by HTTP url, what's in the server's access log? It should show the remote ip there, even if php can't.

Comment: It appears they were running in batches of three. When I entered crontab and commented out the one entry there, it brought it down to two! So apparently, there are two more hidden jobs somewhere calling this script, but they aren't visible via `crontab -e`

Comment: Marc B, thanks for the answer. When I checked the access logs, I showed external IPs hitting the cron. I can now deny them.

Comment: After the suggestion to review my access logs, I discovered that there were external servers hitting my cron job because it was in the website root. I am now disallowing those IP addresses using .htaccess rule. Marc, if you post your answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 0):

cron normally is a well written software and does not do such esoteric things. If it would, you won't be the only one experiencing it. At least as root you are able to see all crontab entries on a system.

Disable the cronjob and see if it still gets executed. If yes, track the source of these HTTP requests with your webserver's access log (especially as they happen every minute). Block these requests.